# Drupal 7 Node Content Type Template Path

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-templates

I am working on a module for Drupal 7. I have a template defined for my content type as node--[content type].tpl.php and placed it in the "themes/[selected theme]/template" directory. I want to keep this template in my "module" directory instead. So when the module is installed I don't have to place the file in to the selected theme folder every time. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you all in advance.

I have less than 10 rep so I cant answer my own question so I'll just modify the question

The following is working for me some how. For both case node edit form view and node view

```
function [content type]_theme() {
   return array(
    '[content type]_node_form' => array(
          'arguments' => array(
              'form' => NULL,
            ),
        'template' => 'node--[content type]--edit',
        'render element' => 'form',
        ),
    'node__[content type]' => array (
          'variables' => array(),
          'template' => 'node--[content type]' ,
          'base hook' => 'node',
          'path' => "sites/all/modules/[content type]_update/[content type]_update/[content type]/",
        ),
    );
}
```

I don't completely understand this but it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should get you going:
http://www.wdtutorials.com/2011/06/13/drupal-7-how-create-custom-theme#.U6sZ741dXag

You basically want to create a new custom theme.
In addition to the above tutorial, create a new folder 'templates' and add your .tpl files in there instead of the core themes folder.

Comment: Actually some one before me worked on the module. He has created a template node--[content type]--edit.tpl.php which is attached to the edit form of the [content type]. I found a this code 
`function [content type]_theme() {
     return array(
     '[content type]_node_form' => array(
             'arguments' => array(
             'form' => NULL,
       ),
       'template' => 'node--[content type]--edit',
       'render element' => 'form',
       ),
     );
}`
I dont Know how to do similar thing for my node [content type] view

Comment: you need to add the path element to the array. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927679/3147901

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below format to specify the template path. Then you can place the tpl file in your module folder.

```
function MODULENAME_theme() {
    return array(
        'yourcustom_theme' => array(
            'template' => 'mypage', // template file called mypage.tpl.php
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME'),
        )          
    );
}
```